# Get user input from textarea

Tags: data-binding, angular, textarea, angular-ngmodel

I'm new to angular2. I want to store user input from a text area in a variable in my component so I can apply some logic to this input. I tried `ngModel` but it doesn't work. My code for the textarea:

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="4" [(ngModel)] = "str"></textarea>
```

And inside my component:

```
str: string;
//some logic on str
```

But I don't get any value in `str` inside my component. Is there an error with the way I'm using `ngModule` ?

Comment: I don't think spaces are aloud in between angular properties and values. That may explain the issue

Answer (score 90):

```
<pre>
  <input type="text"  #titleInput>
  <button type="submit" (click) = 'addTodo(titleInput.value)'>Add</button>
</pre>

{
  addTodo(title:string) {
    console.log(title);
  }
}
```

Comment: In which scope can I use the titleInput ID? I had a workin example like this and rearranged code for styling issues but know it says: Cannot read 'value' of undefined

Comment: This is more of a workaround of using the input tag when the author wants the textarea tag.

Answer (score 34):

I think you should not use spaces between the `[(ngModel)]` the `=` and the `str`. Then you should use a button or something like this with a click function and in this function you can use the values of your `inputfields`.

```
<input id="str" [(ngModel)]="str"/>
<button (click)="sendValues()">Send</button>
```

and in your component file

```
str: string;
sendValues(): void {
//do sth with the str e.g. console.log(this.str);
}
```

Hope I can help you.

Answer (score 14):

Tested with Angular2 RC2

I tried a code-snippet similar to yours and it works for me ;)
see [(ngModel)] = "str" in my template
If you push the button, the console logs the current content of the textarea-field. Hope it helps

**textarea-component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'textarea-comp',
  template: `
      <textarea cols="30" rows="4" [(ngModel)] = "str"></textarea>
      <p><button (click)="pushMe()">pushMeToLog</button></p>
  `
})

  export class TextAreaComponent {
    str: string;

  pushMe() {
      console.log( "TextAreaComponent::str: " + this.str);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just in case, instead of `[(ngModel)]` you can use `(input)` (*is fired when a user writes something in the input `<textarea>`*) or `(blur)` (*is fired when a user leaves the input `<textarea>`*) event,

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="4" (input)="str = $event.target.value"></textarea>
```

Comment: What if we want to an input field where we want to have prefilled value as well we want to access that input field in component. Can we do  that?

Comment: Isn't it possible to bind the value without using (input)?

Answer (score 3):

Here is full component example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-box',
  template: `
        <h1>Text ({{textValue}})</h1>
        <input #textbox type="text" [(ngModel)]="textValue" required>
        <button (click)="logText(textbox.value)">Update Log</button>
        <button (click)="textValue=''">Clear</button>

        <h2>Template Reference Variable</h2>
        Type: '{{textbox.type}}', required: '{{textbox.hasAttribute('required')}}',
        upper: '{{textbox.value.toUpperCase()}}'

        <h2>Log <button (click)="log=''">Clear</button></h2>
        <pre>{{log}}</pre>`
})
export class TextComponent {

  textValue = 'initial value';
  log = '';

  logText(value: string): void {
    this.log += `Text changed to '${value}'\n`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces around your `=`:

```
<div>    
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="str" name="str">
</div>
```

But you need to have the variable named `str` on back-end, than its should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form.
control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

use either of these two:

`<textarea [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first"></textarea>`

`<textarea [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></textarea>`

it worked for me.