# How can i select same file with chrome like firefox in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, file, google-chrome

I have an editor where I can add multiple files even though they are same(repeated).

In my case When I select a file from Firefox it will be added to the editor.!
Second time when I reselect the same file it is again adding properly in the editor.! (Working good)

**BUT**

when I use google chrome first time  it is working fine But second time, the same file it is not taking, because the same file is already selected earlier, so it is not taking(When I cancel and add the same file it gets added)

my HTML is something like this:

```
<input type="file"name="addFiles" multiple>
```

I have seen A article which says when I use multiple it gets reset but it's not.!

Anyhow By using following jquery code i got what i want(After adding the file in editor im setting val t empty.!

```
jQuery('input[type=file]').val('');
```

I am using **Angular 4** I don't want to use jquery, how can I do that.?

Comment: you should be using `[ngModel]`

Comment: is it not possible without `[ngModel]`..?

Comment: refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898080/angular2-ang-getting-input-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upload file in Angular 4**

In the my-fileupload.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

import { SendToService } './_service/service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-fileupload',
    templateUrl: './app-my-fileupload.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-my-fileupload.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        SendToService 
    ]
})

export class MyFileuploadComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

    public MyForm : FormGroup;

    public Files = new FormControl();


    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private sendToService: 
    SendToService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.MyForm = this.fb.group({
            Files: this.Files,
        });
    }

    onFileChange(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>event.target.files; // FILE 

            let size = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
            for (let i = 0; i < this.filesToUpload.length; i++) {
                if (this.filesToUpload.size > 5000000) {
                    // Message for file size
                } else {
                    this.MyForm.get('Files').setValue(this.filesToUpload);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    onSubmit(){
        const formObj = this.UploadFile.getRawValue();
        this.sendToService.UploadFile(formObj).subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response) // response = success
            if (response == success) {
                this.MyForm.reset();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the send-to-service.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class SendToService {

    Url_app = 'url';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    UploadFile(formObj: any) {

        let formData = new FormData();

        for (let i = 0; i < formObj.length; i++) {
            formData.append('Files[]', formObj[i], formObj[i]['name']);
        }

        return this._http.post( Url_app , formData);
    }
}
```

In the my-fileupload.component.html file

```
<input id="Files" type="file" #filesInput (change)="onFileChange($event)" 
       [multiple]="true" />
```

**If you do not want to do this**

Use this method

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

this.filesInput.nativeElement.value = ""
```

We use ViewChild and ElementRef to access the input